# How to solve the case when issue in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like the below showed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl a
   WHERE   A.DEVICE_CAT IN
       (CASE :device1
            WHEN 'A' THEN 'a1'
            WHEN 'B' THEN 'b1'
            WHEN 'C' THEN 'c1'
            WHEN 'D' THEN 'd1'
            WHEN 'E' THEN 'e1'
            WHEN 'F' THEN '(f1, f2)'
            ELSE ' '
         END)
```

For the case when `:device1='F'`, I want to choose result where `device_cat in ('f1','f2')`. How to write it? My current query is incorrect for the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a fan of `case` in the `where` clause.  I find the logic hard to follow.  I would break the logic out:

```
WHERE (:device1 = 'A' and A.DEVICE_CAT = 'a1') OR
      (:device1 = 'B' and A.DEVICE_CAT = 'b1') OR
      (:device1 = 'C' and A.DEVICE_CAT = 'c1') OR
      (:device1 = 'D' and A.DEVICE_CAT = 'd1') OR
      (:device1 = 'E' and A.DEVICE_CAT = 'e1') OR
      (:device1 = 'F' and A.DEVICE_CAT IN ('f1', 'f2'));
```

Besides, you can't nest `case` inside the `in` list.